# What can be done if a former supervisor is giving a bad review?

Tags: recommendation-letter

If one suspects that their former grad studies supervisor is giving them a bad review for prospective employers or research opportunities, is there anything that can be done about it? In a country where negative recommendation letters are not legal (though they can refuse to give one).

Comment: Is there really a country that has such a law?

Comment: Was this your dissertation advisor (doctoral level) or something else?

Comment: @Buffy Yes, Germany has that. Which leads to gems such as "Buffy has performed her duties to our full satisfaction." in a German (company) reference a very bad thing, because this is the worst they are allowed to write.

Comment: @Arno, so "coded language" gets used?

Answer (score 3):

Most job applications ask you to provide references or recommendation letters. Usually, you can choose which names you put on that list (and exclude former supervisors if you don't trust their reference).

Comment: What if you trust your former supervisors, but they write bad reference letters?

Answer (score 1):

As the other commenter said, you can pick and choose which letters of reference to provide. If you had a poor relationship with your adviser, or believe that they are slandering you in their letter of recommendation, just move on and ask someone else.

Do you have other professors that would be willing to recommend you? I know someone who did very well in the job market not using their main professor, so it can be done. Particularly if you can replace them with someone who is well known in your field. Otherwise, you could ask your professor to see the letter if you feel comfortable asking, knowing that they may reject.